# Datepicker with multiples inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hy guys,

I'm trying to put various text inputs on my page with datepicker, and I change the function to this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function calendario(id_calendario, DataMin, DataMax) {
var DataMin;
var DataMax;

  $(id_calendario).datepicker({
    dayNamesMin: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
    monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: DataMax,
    minDate: DataMin,
    navigationAsDateFormat: false,
  });
}
</script>
```

And my input looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="data_c" id="data_inicial" onfocus="return calendario(data_inicial,10,30);">
```

The problem is that in order to show the calendar box I need to click twice on each input. (I guess is one to active the function and the second to process the request).

Anyone know how can I make it work with just one click (or when focus). I need to send the DataMin and DataMin through function because they are dynamically and they change on each input.

I have tried changing the onfocus to any other function and nothing changed. Thank you in advance.

I couldn't find anything on http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ to sort it out.

Comment: `calendario(data_inicial ...`  should be `calendario("data_inicial" ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are correct that it is initializing after you focus so you need to find a place before (e.g when they are dynamically changed / added to the dom / whatever)

you could generally initialize all pickers at once by using a classname and data-attributes to pass dynamic data sth like:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function myDynamicChange() {

  // ...

  $('.calendario').each(function(i,val){
    var min = $(val).attr('data-min');
    var max = $(val).attr('data-max');
    $(val).datepicker({
      dayNamesMin: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
      monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      maxDate: max,
      minDate: min,
      navigationAsDateFormat: false,
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

and the generated input then could look like

```
<input type="text" name="data_c" class="calendario" data-min="10" data-max="20">
```

Comment: Thank you John.. it worked very well .
I only put <script>myDynamicChange()</script> on the bottom of my page to initialize it and got good to go"